# unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 192.168.1.82:44442: bind: cannot assign requested address

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding

is it possible to forward port on 2 different services/pods? For example, I have 2 namespace control-plane-1 & control-plane-2. Both are comprised of cassandra databases pods and a stargate. I am successfully able to forward the port and --address for one stargate but when I do port-forward command for 2nd stargate, I get the following error

```
Unable to listen on port 44442: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 192.168.1.82:44442: bind: cannot assign requested address]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{44442 9042}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by running the command from the other control-plane. Previously, I was running the both port-forward commands

```
microk8s kubectl -n control-plane-1 port-forward --address 192.168.1.81 demo-dc1-default-sts-0 44441:9042
microk8s kubectl -n control-plane-2 port-forward --address 192.168.1.82 demo-dc2-default-sts-0 44442:9042
```

from the same control-plan which was causing this issue on running the 2nd port-forward command. So, when I ran the 2nd port-forward command from the other control-plan(with the ip address 192.168.1.82) whose address I wanted to forward through the port-forward command, I didn't get any error.